# How to run Logistic Regression Model on new Data Feed

Tags: pyspark

I am new to spark. Was going over few blogs and problems to get handle of spark and sparkML.
I went over this LR example https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-pyspark-7d78d022ed35

I was able to understand the basics, generating the model, validation etc.

This is where i am stuck. 
- The problem statement is to classify any new "description" into one of the 33 categories.
- And this is where i am totally lost. Meaning say i have a CSV with "descriptions" like "STOLEN AUTOMOBILE" etc. ... how should i use the trained model to map the description to a category.